# Application no longer displaying properly when chart.js is added

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, yarnpkg, webpacker

```
Rails 6
Bootstrap
webpacker
OS: Mac Catalina 10.15.4
```

I want to start using chart.js, with my Rails 6 application and Webpacker. I did the following:

```
yarn add chart.js
```

and I added the following to my app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("chart.js")
```

When I restarted the application, the UI was all messed up. As in, the logo was taking up half the page, and the landing page, that is supposed to display a table, was displaying the table, but it's not formatted. It's as if most, if not all, the page/app formatting information is gone.

When I checked what I changed, it shows that the following files got modified (in addition to the manual modification I did to app/javascript/packs/application.js):

```
package.json, the following was added to the dependencies section:

"chart.js": "^2.9.3"
```

and the file: yarn.lock, the following was added:

```
chart.js@^2.9.3:
  version "2.9.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chart.js/-/chart.js-2.9.3.tgz#ae3884114dafd381bc600f5b35a189138aac1ef7"
  integrity sha512-+2jlOobSk52c1VU6fzkh3UwqHMdSlgH1xFv9FKMqHiNCpXsGPQa/+81AFa+i3jZ253Mq9aAycPwDjnn1XbRNNw==
  dependencies:
    chartjs-color "^2.1.0"
    moment "^2.10.2"

chartjs-color-string@^0.6.0:
  version "0.6.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chartjs-color-string/-/chartjs-color-string-0.6.0.tgz#1df096621c0e70720a64f4135ea171d051402f71"
  integrity sha512-TIB5OKn1hPJvO7JcteW4WY/63v6KwEdt6udfnDE9iCAZgy+V4SrbSxoIbTw/xkUIapjEI4ExGtD0+6D3KyFd7A==
  dependencies:
    color-name "^1.0.0"

chartjs-color@^2.1.0:
  version "2.4.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chartjs-color/-/chartjs-color-2.4.1.tgz#6118bba202fe1ea79dd7f7c0f9da93467296c3b0"
  integrity sha512-haqOg1+Yebys/Ts/9bLo/BqUcONQOdr/hoEr2LLTRl6C5LXctUdHxsCYfvQVg5JIxITrfCNUDr4ntqmQk9+/0w==
  dependencies:
    chartjs-color-string "^0.6.0"
    color-convert "^1.9.3"
```

If I revert the changes, and restart the application, everything is fine. I would like to use chart.js in my application. Any ideas?

Comment: might be a clash with your existing stylesheet?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The only change, is the addition of chart.js using yarn